# Can a Google App Engine Instance create a Request to itself?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using cloud task for async processing of App Engine requests:

```
<app-engine-instance>/request  ->  <task_queue>/longrunning_task
```

I realised that I'm duplicating a lot of code like database models.

A easier solution would be if I could instead make request to itself

```
<app-engine-instance>/request  ->  <app-engine-instance>/longrunning_task
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but why? Perform internal call instead of HTTP request. What do you want to solve?

Comment: I want to keep the request short, iirc there is no way in flask of that request is finishing before everything is done processing, so calling long-running-function directly doesn’t work

Comment: The problem is the timeout. If your long running tack take less than 60s, you can perform a call from your code. Else, you have to use CLoud Task to handle long running task (up to 24h according to your instance class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although duplicating code might sound like a mistake, this is the intended way of performing the operations combining AppEngine and Cloud Tasks, especially for longer tasks.

Requests for AppEngine are [limited to 60 seconds](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/outbound-requests#request_timeouts), while Cloud Tasks do not fall under such limitations. So, as already pointed out by guillaume blaquiere, if your long running task takes less than 60 seconds, you can perform a call from your code. Else, you have to use Cloud Task to handle long running tasks which is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-handled#asynchronous-work).

> For long-running jobs, we recommend using[Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks). With Cloud Tasks, HTTP requests are long-lived and return a response only after any asynchronous work ends.

Having said that, it is possible for an AppEngine instance to send a request to itself. But it is worth to note that AppEngine's requests are probably not going to the same instance originating the request, the only occasion where this will  happen is when there is only one instance and usually this is not a best practice.

Comment: I tested it and it's definitly more then 60s with App Engine -> Cloud Queue -> App Engine. I think it is the limits of App Engine Cloud Task applying here, which is 10 minutes or so.

Comment: If you have tested it to be more than 60 seconds then it must be the time limit for App Engine tasks as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#timeouts).